# Create new column between two elements and between() python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame `data_set` and two infos important in a list

`cond_list = [{'LQ','DA'},{'HJ','OP'}]`.

***Report all information between the two values `LQ and DA` OR `HJ and OP` in new column 'Another Pass' and which condition in the same day and same id.***

*Example:*

Let i, j correspond to the Rank of LQ and DA respective. i<j

- ID 1552, date 1/4/2020, we have Info['LQ'] correspond to Rank = 1 and Info['DA'] correspond to Rank = 4 --> So all information 'Another pass' include [LA, BA] because Rank DA < Rank LA, Rank BA < Rank LQ
- ID 1552, date 5/4/2020, we have Info['LQ'] correspond to Rank = 3 and Info['DA'] correspond to Rank = 7 --> So all information 'Another pass' include [VT,AN,VB] because Rank DA < Rank VT, Rank AN, Rank VB < Rank LQ
- ID 1697, date 15/4/2020, we have Info['LQ'] correspond to Rank = 1 and Info['DA'] correspond to Rank = 4 but there is no information in between these two points so 'Another pass' is empty

**Input:**

| ID | Date | Rank | Info | Horaire | Type | Note |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1552** | **1/4/2020** | **1** | **LQ** | **10:00** | **D** | LVM |
| 1552 | 1/4/2020 | 1 | LQ | 10:10 | A | LVM |
| 1552 | 1/4/2020 | 2 | LA | 10:12 | P |  |
| 1552 | 1/4/2020 | 3 | BA | 10:15 | P |  |
| **1552** | **1/4/2020** | **4** | **DA** | **10:25** | **A** | LVD |
| 1552 | 5/4/2020 | 1 | DT | 11:30 | D |  |
| 1552 | 5/4/2020 | 2 | GR | 11:33 | P |  |
| **1552** | **5/4/2020** | **3** | **LQ** | **11:35** | **D** | LDT |
| 1552 | 5/4/2020 | 3 | LQ | 11:38 | A |  |
| 1552 | 5/4/2020 | 4 | VT | 11:40 | P |  |
| 1552 | 5/4/2020 | 5 | AN | 11:43 | P |  |
| 1552 | 5/4/2020 | 6 | VB | 11:46 | P |  |
| **1552** | **5/4/2020** | **7** | **DA** | **11:55** | **A** | LDF |
| 1552 | 5/4/2020 | 7 | DA | 11:59 | D |  |
| 1552 | 5/4/2020 | 8 | AT | 12:15 | A |  |
| **1697** | **15/4/2020** | **1** | **HJ** | **10:00** | **D** | LVM |
| **1697** | **15/4/2020** | **4** | **OP** | **11:00** | **A** | LVM |

i filtered a table of values containing only two condition elements:

```
mask = df.groupby(['ID', 'Date'])['Info'].agg(set).apply(lambda x: any([y.issubset(x) for y in cond_list]))
data_set = df.set_index(['ID', 'Date']).loc[mask].reset_index()
dt_final = data_set.loc[data_set['Info'].isin(cond.values.ravel())]
```

I gain a new data frame 'dt_final':

| ID | Date | Rank | Info | Horaire | Type | Note |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1552** | **1/4/2020** | **1** | **LQ** | **10:00** | **D** | LVM |
| 1552 | 1/4/2020 | 1 | LQ | 10:10 | A | LVM |
| **1552** | **1/4/2020** | **4** | **DA** | **10:25** | **A** | LVD |
| **1552** | **5/4/2020** | **3** | **LQ** | **11:35** | **D** | LDT |
| 1552 | 5/4/2020 | 3 | LQ | 11:38 | A |  |
| **1552** | **5/4/2020** | **7** | **DA** | **11:55** | **A** | LDF |
| 1552 | 5/4/2020 | 7 | DA | 11:59 | D |  |
| **1697** | **15/4/2020** | **1** | **HJ** | **10:00** | **D** | LVM |
| **1697** | **15/4/2020** | **4** | **OP** | **11:00** | **A** | LVM |

I say an array of values 'Rank':

```
cd = dt_final.groupby(["ID", "Date"])["Rank"].agg(list).tolist()
```

i filter the values in between:

```
for i in cd:
    pr['Another Pass'] = data_set.loc[data_set.Rank.between(i[0],i[-1])].groupby(['ID', 'Date ']).agg({'Info':list})
```

Although it declares all information by the same date and same id, not the required values between two points in the condition *cond_list* and like a example :(

Comment: Can the same ID and Date have both LQ, DA as well as HJ, OP?

Comment: its data is very big and i can't check all of them, but i think there doesn't exist the case where both supply conditions in one day. So i think yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the same ID and Date cannot have both sets of values, you can try:

```
cond_list = [['LQ','DA'],['HJ','OP']]
firsts = [s[0] for s in cond_list]
lasts = [s[-1] for s in cond_list]

another_pass= df.groupby(["ID", "Date"])
                .apply(lambda x: x[x["Rank"].between(x[x["Info"].isin(firsts)]["Rank"].min(), 
                                                     x[x["Info"].isin(lasts)]["Rank"].max(), 
                                                     inclusive="neither")]["Info"].tolist())
                .rename("Another Pass")

>>> output

ID    Date     
1552  1/4/2020         [LA, BA]
      5/4/2020     [VT, AN, VB]
1697  15/4/2020              []
```

If you want to merge this back to your original DataFrame to create the new column:

```
output = df.merge(another_pass, left_on = ["ID", "Date"], right_index=True)

>>> output

      ID       Date  Rank Info Horaire Type Note  Another Pass
0   1552   1/4/2020     1   LQ   10:00    D  LVM      [LA, BA]
1   1552   1/4/2020     1   LQ   10:10    A  LVM      [LA, BA]
2   1552   1/4/2020     2   LA   10:12    P  NaN      [LA, BA]
3   1552   1/4/2020     3   BA   10:15    P  NaN      [LA, BA]
4   1552   1/4/2020     4   DA   10:25    A  LVD      [LA, BA]
5   1552   5/4/2020     1   DT   11:30    D  NaN  [VT, AN, VB]
6   1552   5/4/2020     2   GR   11:33    P  NaN  [VT, AN, VB]
7   1552   5/4/2020     3   LQ   11:35    D  LDT  [VT, AN, VB]
8   1552   5/4/2020     3   LQ   11:38    A  NaN  [VT, AN, VB]
9   1552   5/4/2020     4   VT   11:40    P  NaN  [VT, AN, VB]
10  1552   5/4/2020     5   AN   11:43    P  NaN  [VT, AN, VB]
11  1552   5/4/2020     6   VB   11:46    P  NaN  [VT, AN, VB]
12  1552   5/4/2020     7   DA   11:55    A  LDF  [VT, AN, VB]
13  1552   5/4/2020     7   DA   11:59    D  NaN  [VT, AN, VB]
14  1552   5/4/2020     8   AT   12:15    A  NaN  [VT, AN, VB]
15  1697  15/4/2020     1   HJ   10:00    D  LVM            []
16  1697  15/4/2020     4   OP   11:00    A  LVM            []
```

###### Edit:

For the required rows from the output, you can do:

```
>>> output[((output["Info"].isin(["LQ", "HJ"])) & 
            (output["Type"]=="D")) | 
           ((output["Info"].isin(["DA", "OP"])) & 
            (output["Type"]=="A"))]

      ID       Date  Rank Info Horaire Type Note  Another Pass
0   1552   1/4/2020     1   LQ   10:00    D  LVM      [LA, BA]
4   1552   1/4/2020     4   DA   10:25    A  LVD      [LA, BA]
7   1552   5/4/2020     3   LQ   11:35    D  LDT  [VT, AN, VB]
12  1552   5/4/2020     7   DA   11:55    A  LDF  [VT, AN, VB]
15  1697  15/4/2020     1   HJ   10:00    D  LVM            []
16  1697  15/4/2020     4   OP   11:00    A  LVM            []
```

Comment: For firsts and lasts, it declares that ''set' object is not subscriptable' :(((((

Comment: You need to change them to lists (so we know which is the first and which is last). Sets aren't ordered.